# fail to run project ejected without expo with error 'cannot find a module LogReporter'

Tags: react-native, expo

My react native project is ejected without expo.
While I run "yarn android"
It throws an error "Cannot find module expo/tools/LogReporter"

Here is my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.3",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-expandable-section-flatlist": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.0.19",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-letter-spacing": "^0.0.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-material-textinput": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-pie": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.23",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.9.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rn-viewpager": "^1.2.9",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.3"
}
```

I have tried to remove node_modules and npm install again. But it shows the same result.